# How can there be request rate when there is no request from query console?

Tags: marklogic

I keep refreshing (F5) the status page of the query console server. I confirmed when no one is using query console and there is no request, there is still request rate shown. 
[image]

As you can see in the below status page there is not any request, yet we see on an average 0.4 request/sec for each host. I keep refreshing the page as fast as I can and also confirmed there is no one using query console. So, how is this request rate calculated ?

Answer (score 1):

It is an average on a certain time window. I reloaded QConsole, and the request rate started at 3.9, and continued going down over the following minute until it reached zero.

Also keep in mind that QConsole runs on port 8000, at which also runs the default REST-api. You could check access logs to see who has been accessing what.

HTH!

Comment: mine doesn't go doen to zero but sum up to 0.8 on an average. Access log shows last request at 03/Sep/2018:02:34:36 CDT yet, request rate is not 0.

Comment: Are you sure the server is configured in CDT timezone? You might need to take some timezone difference into account. Open Admin UI, and check the time shown there with the time on your wall clock..

Comment: "I keep refreshing the page as fast as I can" --> This causes requests,

Comment: <DELETE> last comment -- assuming you are actually checking port 8000 (screenshot doesnt show).  If request rate does not drop to 0 and you are postive no applications or infrastructure is making requests to the server (including internal apps) - open a support ticket -- support can assist by providing additional traces to debug what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

If this is the App-Services (port 8000) app-server status you are checking, have you looked at the access log?